# REST-Driver ClientDriverRule error on instantiation

Tags: java, rest, junit, httpclient

I decided to try the [rest-driver](https://github.com/rest-driver/rest-driver) library for my unit tests.
I have the following code:

```
public class RemoteSessionAccountantTest {

  @Rule
  public ClientDriverRule driver = new ClientDriverRule();

  // ...

  @Test
  public void singleUserSession() throws IOException, JSONException {

    driver.addExpectation(
            onRequestTo("http://myTestUrl/anyUsername").withMethod(Method.GET),
            giveResponse("[{\"contractCode\":\"1234\"}]", "application/json"));

    // ...
  }

// ...

}
```

But I'm not even reaching the test case because instantiating the ClientDriverRule results in an error:

> com.github.restdriver.clientdriver.exception.ClientDriverSetupException:
>   Error starting jetty on port 0
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Local port was not set

Now I've tried setting a specific port, but it didn't help.

I have jetty v9.3.0 (also tried versions 8.x.x, 9.1.x, 9.2.x with no luck)

rest-client-driver version 1.1.42

The problem seems to be coming from jetty, but I cannot figure out what exactly.

Comment: I am not familiar with the `ClientDriverRule`, but reading its' javadoc, I would suggest to try to use `driver = new ClientDriverRule(60000);` so that it runs with a specified port. In case that port is not acquireable, check your firewall.